# Gnuplot plot time as X-axis

Tags: gnuplot

file1

```
Dec 28 00:49:41 52.20  
Dec 28 00:49:45 50.34
Dec 28 00:49:49 52.20
```

Hello. So I did `set timefmt "%b%d%H:%M:%S"` and then `plot "file1" using 1:2 with lines` but I get warnings saying

`Warning: empty x range [9:9], adjusting to [8.91:9.09]`

`Warning: empty y range [8:8], adjusting to [7.92:8.08]`

and the graph range is incorrect

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Thanks! Please add it to the question and not as a comment, by clicking on "edit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data has only blanks between columns, yet it also has blanks internal to the time format.  This is confusing the program, which thinks your "column 2" is really column 4.  Try

```
  plot "file1" using 1:4 with lines
```

But first check that your time format is correct.  Maybe "%b %d %H:%M:%S" (note spaces)?

Comment: Yes, the spacing and column was incorrect. I also added `set xdata time` before `set timefmt "%b%d%H:%M:%S"` and that helped me to solve the problem. Thanks!